# traversing xpath further from selected node

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have following html structure

```
<div class="ac_x">
    <h3>
        <a href="">Title</a>                
    </h3>
    <a class="">
        <img title="" />
    </a>
    <dl>
        <dt class="">Person</dt>
        <dd class="">
        <dt class="ac_i_ard">Address</dt>
        <dd class="ac_i_ard">
            <a href="">Target text</a>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

I'm selecting Title using

```
 var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@class='ac_x']/h3/a")
                         .Cast<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode>().
                         .Select ....
```

Now I want to programmatically select next *Target text* under `<dd class="ac_i_ard">`

I tried with

```
node[0].SelectSingleNode(@"../dl/dd[2]/a");
```

but obviously I'm not selecting node

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

how to select node (Target text) programatically from already selected node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another problem is the first `<dd>` tag is not closed. Therefore all of the following sibling are interpreted as child by HtmlAgilityPack. That's why the following works  :

```
var n = node.SelectSingleNode(@"../following-sibling::dl/dd/dd[@class='ac_i_ard']/a");
```

or a bit simpler way :

```
var n = node.SelectSingleNode(@"../following-sibling::dl//dd[@class='ac_i_ard']/a");
```

[[.NET Fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X0Tj90)]

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
../../dl/dd[@class='ac_i_ard']/a
```

or

```
../following-sibling::dl/dd[@class='ac_i_ard']/a
```

Comment: Please can you see this example on .net fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/VzucVw I think I'm close but obviously I'm missing something

Comment: your string html is invalid, because of the missing end tag `</dd>`, change `"<dl><dt class=\"\">Person</dt><dd class=\"\"><dt class=\"ac_i_ard\">Address` to `"<dl><dt class=\"\">Person</dt><dd class=\"\"></dd><dt class=\"ac_i_ard\">Address`

Answer (score 1):

```
var rootNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@class='ac_x']")
foreach(var n in rootNodes)
{
     var titleNode = n.SelectSingleNode(@"h3/a");
     var ddNodes = n.SelectNodes(@"dl/dd[@class='ac_i_ard']]/a");
}
```